# Render comes out really dark and corrupted when resolution is too high!(using eevee)

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I am rendering some 3D scanned walls with hieroglyphics on them and I need them rendered in a really high resolution.

My problem is that when I render with a resolution higher than about 21120x11880 it just comes out as a black image.

Specs:

- ram: 256 Gb
- Gpu: NVIDIA Quadro P5000
- Cpu: intel xeon e5-2640v4  *2 (20 kernels)

Update:
The image doesn't come out black but really dark and corrupted.
When made brighter it looks like this:
[image]

Thats what it should look like:
[image]

Comment: Do you render with GPU? If so, it may be that your graphics card is out of memory. Try CPU rendering instead.

Comment: will try, thanks

Comment: Oh, and you tagged your question with Eevee, maybe switching to Cycles or Blender Internal will help.

Comment: yeah actually iam rendering with eevee, because i got the best results using it. i just realised  that my question is not asked very good